# Will adding images in all mdpi/ hdpi/ xhdpi etc increase the size of app for all devices ? - Android

Tags: android, resolution

I've read ["Supporting Multiple Screens"](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) on the official docs.

I have around 15 activities. I currently have 4 background images. I've randomly assigned a background image to each of the screens in simple XML.

All these images are around 400X800 in the drawable hdpi folder.

Now the problem:
My app looks bad on tablets. The low resolution images are stretched out.. making them very blurry. So, I'm thinking about adding some higher res images.

The question:
So, now I have 4 images in the hdpi folder. (read slowly) ... If I add the same images of higher resolution in the xhdpi folder .... Will a device with screen of hdpi resolution also have to save the other res pics ?

I know that was confusing, below I explain with an example:
Okay, so I have three devices..
One small,
One medium,
One Tablet.

Now I have 3 sets of images in the mdpi, hdpi and xxhdpi.... for each of these.

Now, will the small device's apk file also contain the bigger images which are not used in it? ... I mean, can android choose which images it wants to download (changing the app size for different devices) ...?

Or does it simply download everything (increasing the app size)... and choose later on while running ?

The thing is, my app is like 800kb .... and adding 3-4 background images for large phones or tablets will drive up the app size to 5-6 mb... That's what I don't want.

So, are all the things stuffed in the apk downloaded equally on all phone sizes ? or are the pics downloaded selectively?

Do small phones unnecessarily download the big images too ?(vice-versa for tablets ?)

(I asked this question, because in many android apps , their size says "Variable for different devices" or something like that... and there's no mention of this whatsover, anywhere on the internet. Trust me, I googled for an hour.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Your project size will increases whatever images added in all folders. If you are designing for 4 different screen your apk size will increase automatically. If you want any images common for all screens, then you can create a drawable folder and place the image in it. So it will pick automatically. Both apk size and your project quality  are important. So you should consider image size when adding to the project. By using padding and other xml factors you can adjust screen size by same image also.

Answer (score 0):

The whole apk is downloaded together with all images for all resolutions. As you usually upload only one file to Google Play, the same file is downloaded by everyone.

There is an option do distribute different apk files based on device onfiguration but it is not very convenient to manage.

You can read about publishing multiple apk in here: http://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html